# Surjectivity prevents becoming 0

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function with dense image.  Can there exist a continuous $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ with $g\circ f=0$ but there exists some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which $g(x)\neq 0$?

Comment: You probably need some more conditions here to make the question interesting. Otherwise you can just have $g$ be a constant function.

Comment: If $g(y) = 0$ on a dense subset and $g$ is continuous...

Comment: @Chessanator I did forget the *important* condition that $g$ itself is not identically 0.. or else $g(z)=0$ would trivially work as dioid pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous function is defined by its values on a dense subset of its domain. Hence to determine $g$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ it suffices to consider its values on the image of $f$ - but if $g\circ f$ is identically zero, then $g\equiv0$ on the range of $f$. Since the range of $f$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $g$ is identically zero.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, g can map everything to 0 and that would make g continuous. Maybe I misunderstood the question or you had some constraints you forgot to mention.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the most important condition, namely that $g\neq 0$.